# Can you see historical Google search results to compare new schema to old display?

Tags: google-search, search-results, rich-snippets

We have implemented the structured data to a client's website. So instead of a boring link on Google, it shows a menu, map, etc.

The client wants to know what this link looked like before. We went over it in the beginning but I forgot to get a screenshot. Is there a "way back machine" for Google searches so, I could see what the link used to look like before we have added to structured data?

Comment: I dont think so. Photoshop could be a solution - as he just want to see how it looked like. As long as you know how it looked like, replicate it by yourself.